# Teaching kids knot making on Android

Tags: android, math, educational, accessibility, touchscreen

I am interested in finding and using an Android app that teaches kids knot making. Ideally, besides a compendium of knots, you can also click to drag the lace or rope with the fingers, and do the knot.

I am particularly interesting in the app showing a five year old kid how to tie shoes (by clicking on the lace to hold it, in whichever way, with whichever finger or fingers, and wrapping around to tie going under and make a ribbon and pass the lace under etc.).

Ideally, the app would guide you with visual input to the correct gestures and steps.

Thanks.